# Symfony form display CollectionType field multiple times (based on entity data)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a Member entity which have a OneToMany relation with a MemberSubscription entity.

```
// App\Entity\Member
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MemberRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MemberRepository::class)]
class Member
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'member_', targetEntity: MemberSubscription::class)]
    protected Collection $memberSubscriptions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->memberSubscriptions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, MemberSubscription>
     */
    public function getMemberSubscriptions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->memberSubscriptions;
    }

    public function addMemberSubscription(MemberSubscription $memberSubscription): self
    {
        if (!$this->memberSubscriptions->contains($memberSubscription)) {
            $this->memberSubscriptions[] = $memberSubscription;
            $memberSubscription->setMember($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMemberSubscription(MemberSubscription $memberSubscription): self
    {
        if ($this->memberSubscriptions->removeElement($memberSubscription)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($memberSubscription->getMember() === $this) {
                $memberSubscription->setMember(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This MemberSubscription have a ManyToOne relation with a Magazine entity.
I have two Magazines in database.

I'm trying to create a Member Form with a field memberSubscriptions which is a Collection type of a MemberSubscription Form.

My Member Form look like this :

```
// App\Form\MemberFormType
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Member;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MemberFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('memberSubscriptions', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'    => MemberSubscriptionFormType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false, 'required' => false],
                'allow_add'     => true,
                'prototype'     => true,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Member::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my MemberSubscriptionForm look like this :

```
// App\Form\MemberSubscriptionFormType
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Magazine;
use App\Entity\MemberSubscription;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MemberSubscriptionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
                'label'    => false,
                'required' => false,
                'widget'   => 'single_text',
            ])
            ->add('endDate', DateType::class, [
                'label'    => false,
                'required' => false,
                'widget'   => 'single_text',
            ])
            ->add('subscribedSince', DateType::class, [
                'label'    => false,
                'required' => false,
                'widget'   => 'single_text',
            ])
            ->add('isInternational', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'    => false,
                'required' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => MemberSubscription::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I would like to display a MemberSubscription form for each magazine existing in database.
I'm doing it like this :

```
{% for magazine in magazines %}
                <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6 border border-gray-200 p-6 rounded-lg">

                    <p class="col-span-6 text-xl">
                        STAL
                    </p>
                    
                    <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-3">
                        <label for="member_form_memberSubscriptions___magazine___startDate"
                               class="block text-sm font-medium text-darkgrey">
                            Début d'abonnement
                        </label>

                        {{ form_widget(form.memberSubscriptions.vars.prototype.startDate, {
                            'attr': {
                                'class': 'mt-1 block w-full border border-[#D3D3D3] rounded-md px-2 py-1',
                            }
                        }) }}

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-3">
                        <label for="endOfSubscription" class="block text-sm font-medium text-darkgrey">
                            Fin d'abonnement
                        </label>

                        {{ form_widget(form.memberSubscriptions.vars.prototype.endDate, {
                            'attr': {
                                'class': 'mt-1 block w-full border border-[#D3D3D3] rounded-md px-2 py-1'
                            }
                        }) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-3">
                        <label for="endOfSubscription" class="block text-sm font-medium text-darkgrey">
                            Abonné depuis le
                        </label>

                        {{ form_widget(form.memberSubscriptions.vars.prototype.subscribedSince, {
                            'attr': {
                                'class': 'mt-1 block w-full border border-[#D3D3D3] rounded-md px-2 py-1'
                            }
                        }) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-3">
                        <label for="endOfSubscription" class="block text-sm font-medium text-darkgrey">
                            International
                        </label>

                        {{ form_widget(form.memberSubscriptions.vars.prototype.isInternational, {
                            'attr': {
                                'class': 'mt-1 block w-full border border-[#D3D3D3] rounded-md px-2 py-1'
                            }
                        }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
```

But I got the error "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Field "startDate" has already been rendered, save the result of previous render call to a variable and output that instead.")."

Someone have an idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: When you call `form_widget(form.memberSubscriptions.vars.prototype.startDate` you set the rendered param of the `formView` to true. I wonder if I would not try to create the view for magazines without subscriptions directly in js. I think you can take inspiration from the js code provided in the `CollectionType` Symfony doc.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to use JavaScript to add or remove memberSubscriptions collection into my Member form. I have two Magazines in database, and into my MemberForm I would like to render a MemberSubscriptionForm for each Magazine existing in database. But when I iterate over my magazine and try to render the form I have and error telling me that the field is already rendered

Comment: This is because you can only render one time each formview and you do it with your formWidget. You could also create from the controller a non-persisted MemberSubscription for each missing magazine and add it to your member before calling the template engine